# How to prove that the set of matrices of rank not greater than r is a smooth manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

How to prove that the set of matrices of rank not greater than $r$ is a smooth manifold? That is to prove that $S=\left\{\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_{1}\times n_{2}}: \mathrm{rank}(\boldsymbol{X})\leq r\right\}$ is a smooth manifold. What is its dimension?

Comment: Can you realize $S$ as the zero-set of a family of functions? Hint: if a matrix has rank $r$, then all $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ minors will be zero.

Comment: I know that the set of matrices of fixed rank $r$ is a smooth manifold. This proof can be found in John M. Lee's book called "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". In my problem, the rank of the matrix is not greater than $r$. I didn't understand what you mean, could you give me more details?